# How to avoid displaying x-axis labels without any associated data in seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

[image]

To make the plot above, I do this:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.factorplot('State', ' % Overall Match', hue='experiment', data=df_states, col='percentile', kind='box', col_wrap=2, sharex=False)
```

Is there a way to NOT display the x-axis labels that do not have nay associated data?

-- EDIT: Data is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pn7j95sjjb9n8t0/old_all.csv?dl=0

Comment: Do you want to empty the space taken by the data not being there, or do you want to remove the ticklabels at those positions that do not have any data associated? Also note that you would increase your chances of obtaining a satisfying answer dramatically by supplying a [mcve] with some that can be used to show a possible solution.

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I want to remove the ticklabels at those positions that do not have any data associated with them

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pn7j95sjjb9n8t0/old_all.csv?dl=0

Comment: This might be a good start: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do this manually:

```
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(2,2)
axes = ax_array.flatten()

for ax, perc in zip(axes, df_states['percentile'].unique()):
     sns.boxplot('State', ' % Overall Match', hue='experiment',
                 data=df_states[df_states['percentile'] == perc], ax=ax)
```